# VLCLib compile for multiple architectures

Tags: android, cross-compiling, vlc, libvlc

I'm struggling with an issue compiling VLCLib. I successfully compiled it, generating the .aar file that I can include in my project. But I can only do that for one Android ABI that I specified in my ~/.bashrc file.

According to [the documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/), run the script compile.sh, and it will generate binaries and an .aar file for the declared architecture in the bashrc variable. But if I change it and run compile.sh again it removes previously generated binaries and only keeps the new architecture. Is there a way to generate a multi architecture that I can use in armeabi-v7a and also in x86? So I don't have to release an platform-specific APK of my project?